# Adding jar file to add class in a java project using ant command line

Tags: java, android, ant, jar, import

I have looked for hours on the net but could not find an answer to the following question(s)...
I have an android project that runs OK using "ant release" command line (for various reasons I cannot use Eclipse nor Android Studio, etc.) on MacOSX. I need to extend a 3rd-party class that consists in a jar file (called mididriver.jar).
I added the following line in my main java source file :

import mididriver.*;

What do I need to add to my build.xml file and where should I put the mididriver.jar file in my project folder structure so that it does not give me a "package mididriver does not exist" error?

Many thanks (in advance) !

Here is the content of my build.xml which WORKS BEFORE I ADD the new class:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="debug">
  <loadproperties srcFile="local.properties"/>
  <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties"/>
  <target name="clean" depends="android_rules.clean">
    <delete dir="libs"/>
    <delete dir="obj"/>
    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build" dir="${basedir}" failonerror="true">
      <arg value="clean"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
  <target name="-pre-build">
    <condition property="makefileConfig" value="Debug" else="Release">
      <equals arg1="${ant.project.invoked-targets}" arg2="debug"/>
    </condition>
    <condition property="ndkDebugValue" value="NDK_DEBUG=1" else="NDK_DEBUG=0">
      <equals arg1="${ant.project.invoked-targets}" arg2="debug"/>
    </condition>
    <condition property="app_abis" value="armeabi-v7a" else="armeabi-v7a">
      <equals arg1="${ant.project.invoked-targets}" arg2="debug"/>
    </condition>
    <exec executable="${ndk.dir}/ndk-build" dir="${basedir}" failonerror="true">
      <arg value="--jobs=2"/>
      <arg value="CONFIG=${makefileConfig}"/>
      <arg value="${ndkDebugValue}"/>
      <arg value="APP_ABI=${app_abis}"/>
    </exec>
    <delete file="${out.final.file}"/>
    <delete file="${out.packaged.file}"/>
  </target>
  <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml"/>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after many failures to try to define the lib folder, I put the jar file in the existing libs folder and now get a successful build...

Answer (score 1):

Create a lib directory in your project

```
my-project
   src
   target
   lib
```

Put the jar into the lib directory.

Modify the javac task to add the lib directory to the classpath.

```
<path id="lib.dir">
    <fileset dir="./lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<javac srcdir="src" destdir="target/classes" >
   <classpath refid="lib.dir"/>
</javac>
```

I don't know which target does not work for you. Is it javac? Or ndk-build? I don't know how to specify class path for ndk-build. There must be some option like `-classpath`.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg. As I don't have defined src.dir nor target.classes.dir variables I tried to to hard code them but I get the following error:
Buildfile: /Users/AG/Documents/MyProject/Builds/Android/build.xml
    [javac] /Users/AG/Documents/MyProject/Builds/Android/build.xml:10: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/AG/Documents/MyProject/Builds/Android/bin/classes

BUILD FAILED
/Users/AG/Documents/MyProject/Builds/Android/build.xml:10: Reference libs.dir not found.

Comment: please see my build.xml file in the edited question. This worked (I was able to  compile and run the app with ant release command) before I added the new class (mididriver.jar).

Comment: @DrMad I modified my answer based on a real build file

Comment: Now it's worse... I get  "package android.app does not exist", "package android.content does not exist", etc. PLUS it still cannot find the new jar file ("package mididriver does not exist"). I'm desperate... :(